# Remove user from site group using PnP-SP in JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, sharepoint-rest-api, pnpjs

I'm trying to find a way to remove a user from a group using PnP-SP. My code is as follows:

```
this.$pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.getById(this.selectedGroup.Id).users
              .remove(user)
              .then(arrResults => {...
```

The error message is:

```
t.$pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.getById(...).users.remove is not a function
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the user from SharePoint group using user Id or user login name.

Using User Id:

```
let userId: number = 1; //replace value with actual user id
this.$pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.getById(this.selectedGroup.Id).users.removeById(userId).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
})
```

Using Login Name:

```
let userLoginName: string = "i:0#.f|membership|user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"; //replace value with actual user login name
this.$pnp.sp.web.siteGroups.getById(this.selectedGroup.Id).users.removeByLoginName(userLoginName).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! For some reason there is not a lot of documentation on this topic so thank you very much for your wisdom sir.

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!